# On change not working on radio group buttons

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

This is the coffee script I have written to do something on change on a  group of radio buttons

```
ready = ->
  $('input[type=radio][name="child[payment_plan]"]').on 'change',  ->
    alert("asd")
    if $(@).val == "normal"
      alert("asd1")
      $("#child_payment_plan_amount").prop('disabled', true)
      $("#child_payment_plan_amount").prop('readonly', true)
    else
      alert("asd2")
      $("#child_payment_plan_amount").prop('disabled', false)
      $("#child_payment_plan_amount").prop('readonly', false)

$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load",  ready
```

Here is the erb on which the above works

```
           <div class="row"><!-- row 4 -->
              <div class="col-8 nopadding">
                <div class="controls">
                  <p>Payment Plan</p>
                  <%- ["normal", "weekly", "bi_weekly", "monthly"].each do |x| %>
                  <%= "#{x.camelize} plan" %>
                    <%= f.radio_button :payment_plan, x, checked: (f.object.child_specific_fee ? (x == f.object.child_specific_fee.payment_plan ? true : false ): x == "normal" ? true : false), class: "form-control child_payment_plan" %>
                  <%- end %>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /col-4 -->
            </div><!-- /row 4 -->

            <div class="row"><!-- row 4 -->
              <div class="col-8 nopadding">
                <div class="controls">
                  <p>Payment Plan Amount</p>
                  <%= f.number_field :payment_plan_amount, value: f.object.child_specific_fee ? f.object.child_specific_fee.amount : nil, step: 0.01, class: "form-control", readonly: f.object.child_specific_fee ? false : true, disabled: f.object.child_specific_fee ? false : true %>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /col-4 -->
            </div><!-- /row 4 -->
```

The resultant HTML is:

```
           <div class="row"><!-- row 4 -->
              <div class="col-8 nopadding">
                <div class="controls">
                  <p>Payment Plan</p>
                  Normal plan
                    <div class="iradio_flat-blue checked" style="position: relative;"><input type="radio" id="child_payment_plan_normal" name="child[payment_plan]" checked="checked" value="normal" class="form-control child_payment_plan"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
                  Weekly plan
                    <div class="iradio_flat-blue" style="position: relative;"><input type="radio" id="child_payment_plan_weekly" name="child[payment_plan]" value="weekly" class="form-control child_payment_plan"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
                  BiWeekly plan
                    <div class="iradio_flat-blue" style="position: relative;"><input type="radio" id="child_payment_plan_bi_weekly" name="child[payment_plan]" value="bi_weekly" class="form-control child_payment_plan"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
                  Monthly plan
                    <div class="iradio_flat-blue" style="position: relative;"><input type="radio" id="child_payment_plan_monthly" name="child[payment_plan]" value="monthly" class="form-control child_payment_plan"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /col-4 -->
            </div>

            <div class="row"><!-- row 4 -->
              <div class="col-8 nopadding">
                <div class="controls">
                  <p>Payment Plan Amount</p>
                  <input type="number" id="child_payment_plan_amount" name="child[payment_plan_amount]" disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" step="0.01">
                </div>
              </div><!-- /col-4 -->
            </div>
```

I have referred many questions, it does look like my coffeescript is okay. But the code on change is not getting triggered. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Possible problems could be:

1. That coffeescript file isn't being loaded on the page. Try putting an alert at the top of the ready function just to be sure.
2. The HTML is being added to the DOM after the coffeescript is run. Maybe it's loaded by Ajax or built dynamically?

Try typing `$('input[type=radio][name="child[payment_plan]"]')` into the javascript console and check that it really does find some matching elements.

If that works, try adding the event in the console too:

```
$('input[type=radio][name="child[payment_plan]"]').on('change', function(){alert("asd3")});
```

Finally, if your browser supports it, I would recommend using `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. Not only is `alert()` more annoying but it can also trigger additional events (e.g. `blur`) which can confuse things.

Comment: 1. I tried that I got an alert.
2. The part of the form is not loaded in ajax.
I have tried the selector in the console and it works while to code on change does not work.

Comment: Maybe you should use `click` instead of `change`? See http://jsfiddle.net/UTwGS/ for a demo of what happens. I believe that `click` is more likely to happen in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=radio][name="child[payment_plan]"]').on 'change',  ->
```

instead try this :-

```
$('input:radio[name="child[payment_plan]"]').on 'change',  ->
```